# Change color in datagridview and SQL database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, colors, sql-server-2008-express

How can I change the color of my Datagridview using C# so that all users connected to a database will see the color? For example a superuser selects that a row should be red, and other people connected to the database loading the datagridview will show in red. Can I do this with conditional statements? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Data and DataBases dont have colors, so there that too.  read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I understand that, I am using sql express 2008 and C# as the language and am using visual studios 2017 as me IDE. I am using the datagridview to view the information from my data table. the program runs on multiple machines and I need to have the rows/cells to change color based on user input. The hardest part is to have anyone connected to the database be able to see the color change on their machine.

Comment: You would need to store the desired row color somewhere, easiest will be on another table, like RowID 3 Color Red, the client code thus will either insert/update/delete the color table for admin login, or just read it for everyone else.